# How to count how many integer elements in array that are equal in java?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, counting

Say I have an array of 3 integers. I want to be able to obtain these results from these arrays using just if statements or a for loop.

```
[0,1,2] = 0 equal
[0,1,0] = 2 equal
[0,0,0] = 3 equal
```

This what i have so far and it works, but I think it could be simplified.

```
int numequal = 0;

if(intarr[0] != null && intarr[1] != null && intarr[0].numequals(intarr[1])) {
    numequal++;
}

if(intarr[0] != null && intarr[2] != null && intarr[0].numequals(intarr[2])) {
    numequal++;
}

if(intarr[1] != null && intarr[2] != null && intarr[1].numequals(intarr[2])) {
    numequal++;
}

if(numequal == 1) {
    numequal = 2;
}
```

Also, I'm trying to keep it basic. Maybe just for loops. No hash sets or dictionaries.

Comment: You might have noticed that your code only works with arrays of size 3.  You should strive to write a reusable method which works for arrays of any size (including 0).  A few hints:  you'll need a loop (in fact, you'll need a nested loop).

Comment: Doesn't look very scalable - what if the array had 1000000 elements? What would your code look like then?

Comment: I want to do it with just a for loop.

Comment: Dude, he's learning to program.  Let him learn to walk first.

Comment: With a for loop, you can iterate over the elements of an array by iterating over an integer index which varies between 0 and "array_size - 1".

Comment: I am scared of even thinking to write 1000000 if statements.....

Comment: what should be  the output for [0,1,1,2,2,2] 3 or 5 ?
You need the count of the maximum repeated number (3) .. or the count of all numbers that are repeated at least once (5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for really simple solution so I tried to optimize your code a bit:

```
int[] intarr = {'0','1','2'};
int numequal = 0; 

if(intarr[0] == intarr[1] || intarr[0] == intarr[2] ){
    numequal++;
}
if( intarr[1] == intarr[2]){
    numequal++;
}

if (numequal > 0 ){
    numequal++;
}
```

if your array is declared as `int[]` there is no need to check for `nulls`
 `intarr[1] != null`.

If some item is not set, it will be default `0`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It is not simple but very efficient. Currently it counts null elements too, which can easily be fixed if it's undesirable.

```
    Integer[] a = { null, 2, 1, null, 0, 1 };
    Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            if (o1 == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    // [null, null, 0, 1, 1, 2]
    int n = 0;
    Integer prev = null;
    Boolean first = null;
    for (Integer e : a) {
        if (first != null && (e == prev || e != null && e.equals(prev))) {
            if (first == Boolean.TRUE) {
                n += 2;
                first = Boolean.FALSE;
            } else {
                n++;
            }
        } else {
            first = Boolean.TRUE;
        }
        prev = e;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: Seems too complicated to me.Since your comparison function takes `null` into account why don't you just iterate over the first non null element (`O(N)`) and then just compare adjacent elements?No need to take corner cases i.e. `null` into account? Also why are you using `Boolean` and not `boolean`?

Comment: Since it is not a primitive array and nulls are allowed you need that special Comparator otherwise Arrays.sort would fail. Boolean is used because it is also a flag of processing a[0].

Comment: `Since it is not a primitive array and nulls are allowed you need that special Comparator otherwise Arrays.sort would fail.` What does this have to do with my comment?

Comment: I mean that Comparator adds compexity to the program

Comment: Your comparator puts all `null` values in the start of the array followed by the actual values. So after sort, just skip over `null` entries (`O(N)`) and then start to look for equal adjacent pairs. You will not need any corner cases for this area of the array

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the easiest way (some may beg to differ):

```
int[] x = { 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 9,
    7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 6 };
int rep = 0;
int finalc = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  int basec = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
    if (x[i] == x[j]) {
      basec++;
    }
  }
  if (basec > finalc) {
    finalc = basec;
    rep = x[i];
  }
}

System.out.println("The number " + rep + " is repeated " + finalc +" times");
```

This will print:

```
The number 6 is repeated 8 times
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm question, which can be optimizez.....

I would use an un-synchronized key-value storage, for the key I would put the int as string, for the value his counts.

Frtst you will try to get it like: hashMap.get("0") if it return null, than the count is 0, than put it back: hashMap.put("0", new Integer(1)).

Unless you don't need, than use the unsynchronezed version of hashMap, searc it with google!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array.sort and count them nicely:

```
    int[] a = {0,1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1 };
    int size = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    //sort it and you will get all the equal inters in a sequance.
    Arrays.sort(a);// {0,0,1,1,2,3}
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){          
        if ( a[i-1] == a[i]){
            counter++;
            if(counter  > size){
                size = counter;
            }
        }else{
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    return size;
```

Comment: Start with `i = 1` and remove the `if(i == 0)`